# Regex - replacing part of a matched group possible?

Tags: sed, splunk

Is it possible to replace half or x characters of a matched group?

I have had a request for a partial email capturing, so something like `example123@abcdef.com` becomes `***mple123@***def.com`

I can do this if the characters before and after the @ are 3 characters long,

`([^|@]{0,3})([^]{0,3})`

This captures `123@abc.com` perfectly and I can substitute for `***@***.com` but if it's over 3 characters long on each end, for instance `example123@abcdef.com` it becomes `******e123@abcdef.com`

The other way I can see is capture everything until the `@` and everything to the `.` but then this won't be a partial capture. Is this possible?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/(^|@)[^@]{0,3}/\1***/g'`

Comment: Regular expressions by themselves only match. You can often use the surrounding language's facilities to pull out parts of the match, though. Splunk has capturing groups so you can refer back to parts of the match and piece them together with the `rex` command.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, this works, though when the email has <3 chars each side it doesn't

Comment: @tripleee I won't be tabling it or anything. This will just be to mask it partially so trying to do it via rex sed

Comment: The question is unclear in that regard; you tagged it `sed` which is the name of a Unix command, so e.g. Wiktor's comment above relates to that. Probably [edit] to clarify this and remove the misleading tag, and show us in more detail what you tried and where you are stuck. I probably won't be able to help with the Splunk query language in more detail, other than vaguely advise you to try to use something less horrible if at all possible.

Comment: `sed` can be used in Splunk, and probably that is fine to keep both tags. What email addresses do not fit my top comment solution? Please update the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew all good, changed the second @ to a . and it's all working, thanks 
`sed -E 's/(^|@)[^.]{0,3}/\1***/g'`
initially wasn't working with something like a@a.com

Comment: I do not think so, ``23@a.com`` will turn into `***a.com` then. `sed -E 's/^[^@]{0,3}|(@)[^.]{0,3}/\1***/g'` will be safer.

Comment: Please check my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/^[^@]{0,3}|(@)[^.]{0,3}/\1***/g'
```

*Details*

- `-E` - enables the POSIX ERE syntax that does not require too much escaping here
- `^[^@]{0,3}` - zero to three occurrences of any char other than a `@` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `(@)` - Group 1: a `@` char
- `[^.]{0,3}` - zero to three occurrences of any char other than a `.`
- `\1***` replaces with Group 1 value + `***`.